# How to find the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{∞} \frac{k^2}{(k+1)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I've tried to find the sum of $\sum_{k=1}^{∞} \frac{k^2}{(k+1)!}$ and calculator says its sum is $e-1$. I thought that it is related to the Maclaurin series of $e$, well I could not derive the $-1$ term for answer. What is an elementary way to derive the answer? Thank you for your help.

Comment: There's no way a finite sum of rationals would be something irrational like $e-1$. Don't you intend to have a sum up to infinity?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Hello, sorry. It was my mistake. I'll edit the post. Thanks :)

Comment: This is a special case of [Dobiński's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobiński%27s_formula).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^2}{(k+1)!}
 &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k(k+1)}{(k+1)!}
  - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k+1}{(k+1)!}
  + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+1)!} \\
 &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k-1)!}
  - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}
  + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+1)!} \\
 &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}
  - \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} - 1\right)
  + \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+1)!} - 1 - 1 \right)\\
 &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} - 1 \\
 &= e - 1.
\end{split} 
$$

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. I almost understood, but I wonder where two $-1$ terms were come from on third line, $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(k+1)!} -1-1$. Thanks.

Comment: @cumulonimbuscloud $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+1)!} = \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} - \frac{1}{0!} - \frac{1}{1!}$$